Microphone access for a deployed Gradio app on E2
I need to create a demo to test an STT Agent. I created a simple Gradio app and deployed it on EC2 instance. However, when I launch it, my browsers(Safari and Chrome) report no microphone provided. Is it possible to deploy the app in a way that allows microphone access?
I've included a basic example of my Gradio app, which also doesn't work.
import gradio as gr

audio = gr.Microphone(sources=["microphone"], type="filepath")
ui = gr.Interface(
    fn=lambda x: x,
    inputs=audio,
    outputs=audio,
    allow_flagging="never"
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ui.launch(server_name="0.0.0.0")

I tried to change port, but the results are the same. I also tried to use NGINX, but I couldn't write a proper script.
